# "Unresolved Reference" when Interop-ing C Library

Tags: c, kotlin, kotlin-interop, kotlin-native

I am trying to make a militaristic example of reading and executing C code within Kotlin-Native. I am following this article [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/interop-with-c.html). However, I'm receiving an "Unresolved Reference" error on the final step. Here are all the files/commands I'm using. *My operating system is Windows.*

**testlib.h**

```
#ifndef MY_TEST_LIB
#define MY_TEST_LIB

int getRandomNumber();

#endif
```

**testlib.c**

```
#include "testlib.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getRandomNumber() {
    return rand();
}
```

I've compiled these files into a static library named `libtestlib.lib`. My goal is to call `getRandomNumber` from within Kotlin Native.

---

Next I have these kotlin related files:

**testlib.def**

```
headers = testlib.h
headerFilter = ./*
compilerOpts = -L. -ltestlib -I.
```

**CLibTest.kt**

```
import testlib.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(getRandomNumber())
}
```

---

Finally, I'm running these two commands. 
The first to make the `klib`:

`cinterop -def testlib.def -o testlib`

---

And then this last one to create the executable:

`konanc CLibTest.kt -library testlib`

Everything works great until this last command, where I receive the following error:

`CLibTest.kt:4:10: error: unresolved reference: getRandomNumber
        println(getRandomNumber())`

---

Could someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Your function name may have been [decorated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C). May be try with `_getRandomNumber()`

Comment: @purplepsycho Interesting. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the solution. Still resulting in an identical error, only with `_getRandomNumber()` this time. >.<

Comment: Not an expert in this area, but what if in  *testlib.h* file you declare the function: `__declspec(dllexport) int getRandomNumber();`? This is only to check if exporting is the real problem, then, if so, the export logic should look smth like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581837/linker-error-when-calling-a-c-function-from-c-code-in-different-vs2010-project/30583411#30583411, (or simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507196/python-ctypes-to-return-an-array-of-function-pointers/51529527#51529527).

Comment: You can use the [`dumpbin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y05bd5.aspx) tool to know how the name hase been mangled: `dumpbin /HEADERS testlib.lib`

Comment: @CristiFati Sorry, it did not make any difference.

Comment: @purplepsycho I did so, but was unable to ascertain any information regarding mangling?

Comment: Declare it extern "C".

Comment: Btw, the issue is unrelated to the linker.The error message comes from Kotlin compiler (frontend) and means that the declaration wasn't found. While the linker would complain about missing definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the combination of suggestions from Svyatoslav Scherbina and Mike Sinkovsky.

The "headerFilter" was incorrect and needed to be removed, and the static library needed to be embedded to the .klib. By setting **testlib.def** to be:

```
headers = testlib.h
compilerOpts = -I.
staticLibraries = libtestlib.lib
libraryPaths = .
```

The issue is resolved and the kotlin file complies/runs without issue!

Answer (score 2):

Windows libraries must be created by msys2-mingw, not msvc.

Something like this (in mingw64 shell):

```
gcc -c testlib.c -o testlib.o && ar rc testlib.a testlib.o
```

Comment: Sorry, already doing exactly that. I apologize for not clarifying so.

Comment: Ok, then why it is .lib, not .a ?

Comment: Maybe you need to add -static in linkerOpts, or embed static lib in .klib like here: https://github.com/msink/kotlin-pi/blob/master/src/main/c_interop/pi.def

Comment: Oh! The embedding static lib, along with the header filter was it! Thanks so much! ^^

Answer (score 1):

`headerFilter` value in your `testlib.def` is incorrect. You can try to remove it.

The filter is applied to the value written under `#include` directive from headers and `headers` value elements from `.def` file. None of these strings have `./` prefix.

Comment: --I did so and received this error: `.../combined.o:(.text+0x1f0b5): undefined reference to 'getRandomNumber'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`--

Comment: Nevermind, this combined with the embedding the static library into .klib resolved the issue!