# Cross platform c++ integrated with c# in Linux and Windows

Tags: c#, c++, shared-libraries, cross-platform, dllimport

I have the following code in c++ to determine available RAM in os

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "string.h"
#include "setjmp.h"
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

extern "C"
{
    unsigned long long getAvailableSystemMemory_Windows64();
    unsigned long long getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64();
}

#if defined(_WIN32)

__declspec(dllexport) extern unsigned long long getAvailableSystemMemory_Windows64()
{

MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
status.dwLength = sizeof(status);
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&status);
return status.ullAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024;
}

#elif defined(__linux__)

extern unsigned long long getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64()
{

unsigned long long ps = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
unsigned long long pn = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
unsigned long long availMem = ps * pn;
return availMem / 1024 / 1024;
}

#endif

int main()
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    printf("%d", getAvailableSystemMemory_Windows64());
#elif defined(__linux__)
    printf("%d", getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64());

#endif
printf("MB");

int a;
scanf("This is the value %d", &a);
}
```

and the following code in c#

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("hello.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    extern static long getAvailableSystemMemory_Windows64();


    [DllImport("hello.so", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64")]
    extern static long getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long text = 0;
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            text = getAvailableSystemMemory_Windows64();
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            text = getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64();


        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

}

Then in windows I compile c++ code using `g++ --shared  -o hello.dll  hello.cpp` and copy the dll to debug folder. everything is ok.

for Linux I compile it on Opensuse using `g++  -o hello.so  hello.cpp`
and copy the `.so` file into the debug but it doesn't work. 
I get the exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared 
library 'hello.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose 
loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: 
libhello.so.so: cannot dynamically load executable
at CallCDll.Program.getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64()
at CallCDll.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
/home/CallCDll/Program.cs:line 22
```

I added the `.so` file dir path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/CallCDll/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2` but doesn't work.

What Should I do? Wherever I copy the `.so` file, it cannot find it.

Comment: I'm not much of a Linux man myself but, from the error message it seems you shouldn't include the `.so` part in your `DllImport` line - system is looking for `hello.so.so` (.so: good they added it twice - hehe).

Comment: @Adrian now I get `Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'hello' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libhello: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at CallCDll.Program.getAvailableSystemMemory_Linux64()
   at CallCDll.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/CallCDll/Program.cs:line 22
`

Comment: Damned if you do, damned if you don't! Like I said, I'm not really a Linux man. But why also is it looking for "libhello" rather than "hello?" Have you tried simply renaming your `hello.so` to `libhello.so.so` ??

Comment: Did you declare your C++ function as `extern "C"` to prevent the compiler from mangling it?

Comment: @Adrian I don't know too

Comment: @Botje Yes, I have added

Comment: There are certainly better ways to check for available system memory than using extern DLLs

Comment: The shared object should be called libhello.so. Try `g++  -o libhello.so  hello.cpp`. https://www.tecmint.com/understanding-shared-libraries-in-l

Comment: Why is the **`-shared`** flag missing from the *Lnx* command? Note that it would also imply **`-fPIC`**. Also, not sure why *func*s are *extern*.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks man. It worked . `g++ -o libhello.so hello.cpp --shared -fPIC
` I used this.

Comment: @unosbaghaii: :) One more question: Does it still work if you name the lib *hello.so* (`-o hello.so`)? Assuming that the *C#* code is unchanged: `[DllImport("hello.so", ...`. According to the error message you got, it should work as that's the library that's being attempted to load.

Comment: @CristiFati in c# is `[DllImport("hello.so", ...`.  it works with both `-o hello.so` and `-o libhello.so` in debug folder. Apparently it searches for both names

Comment: @unosbaghaii: It's what I expected. But when building *libhello.so* did you delete *hello.so* before running your program?

Comment: Here's some interesting approach https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709270/Csharp-NET-Interoperability-with-Native-C-Librarie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Man7]: GCC(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) (`man gcc`):

> **-shared**
>
> Produce a shared object which can then be linked with other objects to form an executable.  Not all systems support this option.  For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options used for compilation (**-fpic**, **-fPIC**, or model suboptions) when you specify this linker option.[1]

So, your command didn't generate a shared object or library (*.so*), but an executable (even if named *hello.so*). If you try running it, you'll see the output from *main*.
To fix things, change your build command to:

```bash
g++ -shared -fPIC -o hello.so hello.cpp
```

Other **notes**:

- Don't know why you made your functions *extern*
- Regarding `__declspec(dllexport)`, the common way of handling it *cross platform* is via a macro. There are many examples (I too have several), here's one: [[SO]: Python ctypes to return an array of function pointers (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51529527/4788546) - *DLL00_EXPORT* macro (or even more generic - as it handles building a static library as well: [[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583411/4788546))
- In terms of naming, usually a library - let's call it "***example***" - will be named ***lib**example.so*. Many *lib*s are still named like that for backwards compatibility: one advantage is when linking against it, only specify the short version (***-lexample***) instead of its name. Check [[SO]: Why are some Windows dll names prefixed by lib (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69439948/4788546) for more details.
  If you decide to change the name, make sure to update your *C#* code as well: `[DllImport("libhello.so", ...`