# Why are some Windows dll names prefixed by lib

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

Why are some C++ dll names prefixed with *lib*, for example **lib**xml2.dll? Does this has some significance?

Comment: no, the name prefix does not have any signifcance.

Comment: It may refer to library, as in a dll with a library of functions but is not required

Comment: When using GCC and its linker looks for libraries it will prepend  `lib` to find libraries. So if you link with `xml2` then it will look for `libxml2.dll` (or possibly its export library `libxml2.a`).

Comment: It's mostly a nix thing. In Windows it's not common for libraries to start with it.

Answer (score 4):

Libraries are used (referenced) at link time. Fore more details, check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546).

#### *Nix* considerations

According to [[Man7]: LD(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

> **-l** *namespec*
>
> **--library=***namespec*
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by *namespec* to the list of files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If *namespec* is of the form *:filename*, **ld** will search the library path for a file called *filename*, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called *libnamespec.a*.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, **ld** may also search for files other than *libnamespec.a*. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, **ld** will search a directory for a library called *libnamespec.so* before searching for one called *libnamespec.a*. (By convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.) Note that this behavior does not apply to *:filename*, which always specifies a file called *filename*.

In other words, it's possible to pass libraries to the *GNU linker*:

1. By name (base or with (absolute or relative) path)
2. Short form: ***-ldummy***. In this case, the linker will search for *libdummy.so* (or *libdummy.a*).

Needless to say that if the *.lib* would be named *dummy.so* (or *dummy.a*), ***#2.* would not work**.

#### *Win* ecosystem

The libraries are passed to the **default (*VStudio*) linker** by name only ([[MS.Learn]: .Lib Files as Linker Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input)). 
However, some maintainers add the ***lib* prefix just to be consistent with the *Nix* name**. 
So, it's just a convention and has no functional value whatsoever.

But nowadays, in order to reduce the gap between the 2 *OS*es, there are **multiple *Nix* tool ports for *Win*** ([MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org), [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org), [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com), ...). Since those "obey" the *Nix* interface, you'd be able to use the short form (from previous chapter), and that would save a lot of headaches especially when porting large projects with *Makefile*s that contain ***-l***.

Comment: The "Nix considerations" also apply to MinGW, so it could have some use on Windows.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I am working on an edit, but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 3):

It is purely a convention and doesn't mean anything more than letting people know it is a library. You can call a dll anything you like